# Dealing with Java Keystore load error: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, websphere, keystore, java-6

I have a legacy Java application trying to load a JKS keystore. The application is able to pick the Keystore from a sharedLibrary but unable to load it when I deploy it on Websphere 8.5 server. Below are code

```
keystore.load(inputStream,keyStorepwd.toCharArray());
```

This is log I see:

````
[12/2/19 17:10:16:162 EST] 0000008d SystemErr     R java.io.EOFException  
[12/2/19 17:10:16:162 EST] 0000008d SystemErr     R     at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:386)
[12/2/19 17:10:16:162 EST] 0000008d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.crypto.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
[12/2/19 17:10:16:162 EST] 0000008d SystemErr     R     at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:415)```
````

Comment: I tried with Java 1.7 as well. However the same error leading me to think something is wrong with the conflicting IBM jar.

Comment: Did you solve it?